# Does 病 refer to a short or long term illness?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji

Does 病 refer to a short or long term illness? I was in a chat and the word was used 
in response to someone chatting about a head cold. I asked the person if they were hospitalized, and they were not. Since the word yamai was used by the other person, I thought that it was more serious, but no hospitalization was required. i see the word yamai relates to illness and 病院 but I can't seem to find a duration.

Comment: What makes you think that the word implies a certain duration?

Comment: the chat was about a cold and the other person used yamai which made me think that the cold may be more serious but I wasn't sure of the word choice in this case.

Comment: do you have the full sentence?

Comment: no, the chat is over. We were chatting about a cold.

Comment: Just some hour ago I was wondering about the difference between 病 and 病気 and found this, does it help? https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/2332035 It also links the Japanese page; I'm noted there it's spelled 病い, while on dictionaries is spelled 病, not sure if there is any difference.

Comment: its similar to yamai

Comment: JACK, please explain your question in detail *before* someone asks. Who used yamai, and what happened? The comment section in your question is almost always full of comments like "why a question like this?" This can be a good question if saved the whole exchange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your trouble amounts to the difference between 病気【びょうき】 and 病【やまい】.

In modern Japanese, *yamai* is a grandiose word that usually refers to serious, often life-threatening diseases. The duration is not important because many serious yamai are acute (like acute brain strokes). On the other hand, *byoki* is a generic and casual term for sickness/illness/disease. If you used *yamai* to refer to a mere cold, it would surprise people.

Comment: Hmm, isn’t even 病気 a bit too serious sounding for a common cold though?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie If a cold is serious enough to make you have a day off, I think that can be safely called a 病気. 病気 is a broad term that covers both sickness and disease. See: https://www.yobiko.co.jp/hiroba/entry-2545/